# How to add two column in pandas

Tags: pandas

Below is the data frame `df`

```
Id,real, imaginary
1,30,7
2,40,-8
3,50,-6
```

psudeo code
`df['z'] = df.apply(lamda x: x['real'] + x['imaginary']* i)`

Expected Out
df['z']

```
30 + 7i
40 - 8i
50 - 6i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df['z'] = [complex(*e) for e in zip(df.real, df.imag)]
```

result:

```py
real  imag                    z
30     7  30.000000+7.000000j
40    -8  40.000000-8.000000j
50    -6  50.000000-6.000000j
```

### How to remove the 0000?

convert the data type of pandas to native python types as follows:

```py
d = df.astype(object)
```

result:

```py
In [60]: df
Out[60]:
   real  imag                    z
0    30     7  30.000000+7.000000j
1    40    -8  40.000000-8.000000j
2    50    -6  50.000000-6.000000j

In [61]: d = df.astype(object)

In [62]:

In [62]: d
Out[62]:
  real imag        z
0   30    7  (30+7j)
1   40   -8  (40-8j)
2   50   -6  (50-6j)
```

Comment: is there any way to remove .00000

Answer (score 1):

Is this complex number ？

```
df['real'] + df['imaginary'] * 1j
0    30.000000+7.000000j
1    40.000000-8.000000j
2    50.000000-6.000000j
dtype: complex128
```

Comment: @Nons this how python handle the complex number ~ if you would like the int , we need to convert it to string, which make no sense ~